# Copy Files from Remote RDP to Local Machine

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way I can launch a RDP session to a remote Windows server, and perform a file transfer to the local computer? Versions of the remote Windows Server varies. Ranges anywhere from 2000 to 2008.

I've tried to look up solutions and it seems scattered everywhere. Some suggest using mstsc.exe, others suggest PowerShell / Java / ASP Net. I'm confused. Appreciate some guidance here.

Thanks!

*Update Below: 17 Feb 2012*

Thanks for all suggestions. Would like to add that the remote servers are securely locked down and I'm not allowed to install SSH servers, FTP servers, or shared drives. The only way for accessing the remote machine is through RDP, and these machines are also on separate VLANs to which only authorised users can use RDP to access these machines. I'm trying to create a script that can help authorised users to download the required files.

Comment: Do you need to use RDP? Can you install an SSH server on the remote windows server and transfer the files that way (using SCP)

Comment: If you can do an RDP session to the server, you should have access to the admin shares (C$, D$, etc) on the servers drives.  You should be able to access and copy file through those without need RDP at all.

Comment: -Alan, I'm not allowed to install an SSH Server.                      -mjolinor, I'm not allowed to add shared drives either.

Comment: Pretty much all (most? ... probably all...) methods of file transfer aren't available to you then.

Comment: If I can use RDP to transfer files from the remote server to my local computer, the qn then is whether I can automate this process?

Comment: Haha, this is so totally not an SO question, it's an SU question.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I believe SU was not yet create at the time of writing?

Answer (score 88):

You can map a drive using remote desktop.

Options > Local Resources > More

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not allowed to do that.

Comment: The RDP client needs to offer an option where the remote drives are brought to your local machine so that you can work remotely and can then sync files back to your local machine (where the sync is initiated locally), and it needs to be tunneled within the RDP session.  Opening up your local drives to the remote machine is a much bigger security hole, at least for me.  And regular SMB access to \\machine is not typically feasible to remote Windows VMs in the cloud.

Comment: Tradeoff: create a network share on your machine and connect that share as a drive (from Explorer, Tools > Map a network drive), then add this drive to the list of drives you want accessible to the remote server. Only the files in this folder are then accessible to the remote server.

Comment: You should also make sure that you have no restrictions on the computer that you are remoting to by running Remote Desktop Services Manager or tsconfig.msc (or tscc.msc) on windows server. See @Nixphoe's answer on this [post](http://serverfault.com/questions/254530/tsclient-share-is-blank-when-rdping-to-remote-windows-server)

Comment: Rather than mapping a whole drive you can map a folder by creating a new drive letter using subst, e.g. subst p: C:\users\Example

Answer (score 88):

Ctrl + C at the Remote Desktop, and Ctrl + V at local, if you not looking for any automated solution. (Please check RD Config to enable copy and paste)

Comment: I wasn't looking for a script solution so thanks for this, @Raymond.

Comment: does not work for me.

Answer (score 27):

Once you have mapped the drives you want using mstsc, you can use `\\tsclient` to access the file system of the local machine i.e the Terminal services client from which you have RDP'ed on to the remote box.

If all you are trying to do is copy file from a remote box, just do `\\machine\c$\path` etc or share the folder and do `\\machine\share` to get them. RDP is not necessary in this case.

Comment: To use `\\tsclient` you have to select drives to bring into the RDP session first in the GUI I screenshotted.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - Not when you are doing `\\tsclient\c` etc. tsclient is literal, not a placeholder for the machine. I will confirm, however.

Comment: Just tried it... No worky unless I first select drives via the mstsc GUI.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - It does seem to work only when the drives are mapped. Having my drives mapped always, I figured this wasn't needed.

Comment: Would probably be a security hole if it always made your local drives accessible... I checked the mstsc flags and there's no option to map them via command line.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - You can pass in a connection file to mstsc and specify redirect drives in it - http://coe.uncc.edu/mosaic/remote_desk/RDP%20File%20Settings.htm

Comment: But that's too much work lol :-)  Sure nuff `drivestoredirect:s:Local Disk (C:);RAID (E:);`

Answer (score 12):

Once you have mapped the needed drives as Andy says, you can execute remotely a **LOCAL** batch file every time you connect specifying it's local path (using `\\tsclient\c` to refer your local drive) in the Programs tab at RDP properties.
Remember to write **cmd /c** before that path.
The rdp connection will automatically close once the batch file ends, but you can add the `pause` command to the end to see what happened during execution.

Connecting this way, you can edit the batch file before connecting.

[image: rdp execute BAT]

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your remote Machine enabled PSRemoting by running the following command in PowerShell

```
Enable-PSRemoting –Force
```

From the client computer, run the following command to establish the connection.

```
net use "\\{RemoteIP}\c$" "{Password}" /USER:"{Username}" /persistent:no
```

Here after you can use Copy-Item, Delete-Item over the network.

```
Copy-Item [PACKAGEPATH]\* \\[COMPUTER]\c$\installers -recurse
```

Answer (score 6):

1. In Client machine, Run->mstsc.exe-> Local Resources-> enable clipboard.
2. In remote machine-> windows run command (Windows Key + R).
3. Open cmd->(Taskkill.exe /im rdpclip.exe) type brackets command
4. You got "Success", then
5. Type same command prompt "rdpclip.exe"
6. Now copy and paste both, its working fine

Answer (score 3):

You can copy and paste files over RDP, it works perfectly. See http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/1d6a1o/til_you_can_copy_and_paste_files_over_rdp/ for more info.

Answer (score 1):

[eug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94078/eug) wrote what I thing is an extremely useful [comment](/questions/9304953/copy-files-from-remote-rdp-to-local-machine#comment40513662_9305105) that seems to have overlooked by everyone:

You can very easily **share a single folder** by using `subst` to map it to a drive letter, and then selecting that drive in remote desktop.

Note that it's fairly easily to have problems with this method due to `subst` performing the mapping only for the user under which it is run.
So I recommend to run everything from a single command prompt:

1. Open a command prompt (Win+R -> cmd)
2. Type `subst <lettertomap>: <pathtofolder>`
3. Type `mstsc` (which launches Remote Desktop)

Keep in mind that the `subst` mappings are not persistent across reboots, of course, so this is mostly convenient for a one-time session of file transfer.

There are actually also other ways to do the mapping, see [raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/map-folder-or-directory-to-drive-letter-for-quick-and-easy-access/) .

And yes, the mapping does seem to disallow access to the rest of the drive, although I wouldn't bet my life that it doesn't have chroot-like "vulnerabilities" (assuming it is supposed to be secure in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

1) Install dropbox or equivalent cloud storage product and sync needed files that way between computers.  Remember, you can allow only certain folders to be synced on specific devices (you don't have to sync the entire dropbox, just the folders you need)

2) If you are allowed to setup more than one user on the remote server, have a 2nd user and then have user2 session connect rdp session to user1.  This will keep the user1's gui alive in the cloud without having to remain logged in to rdp locally.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoybUfW0VdY) should show you how to implement this 2 user setup on your server to hold an rdp session open.  Note that this does 'permanently' use 1 rdp session until you decide to close it.
[markdown cannot embed video :( ]

Then use <s>AmmyyAdmin</s> **[AnyDesk](https://AnyDesk.com)** on user1's desktop to connect and manipulate the desktop.  This includes using AnyDesk's file manager's ability to browse any folder you need and copy.  AnyDesk can be free if you connect via direct IP connection.  Most vps servers have dedicated IP addresss or subdomain address so this should not be a problem.  Good idea to password protect your AnyDesk login and which IDs have access to unattended remote connections.  The AnyDesk file manager is a bit crude, but it works.  Their big thing is simplicity and speed.

Note: **Use portable mode only on the remote user's desktop; Do NOT fully install AnyDesk.**  Also, the CPU usage might increase to stream the desktop screen, somewhat related to the size of the RDP window.  I am using 1280 x 2048 window with 4 cores and the CPU usage is 22-25% idle or moving things around.  This might decrease if there is more video ram or graphics processor on the target server.  But, if you only "browse files" (use only the file manager without streaming the desktop), CPU usage >0.3% idle and >1 avg% when transferring files (burst up to 5-6% when the file is finished uploading and the pieces are being finalized).

You'd have to write your own scripts (java, .net, c#/c++, [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), etc) to launch AnyDesk locally and automate the connecting and downloading specific files.

This strategy is a bit more complex, but it should do the job.  Not sure why microsoft rdp cannot have some simple, quick file manager like what <s>ammyy admin</s> AnyDesk has; oh well.

---

Add:  Can also use [AnyDesk](https://AnyDesk.com) or Teamviewer.  Teamviewer became a lot more restrictive on what is considered to be "non commercial use", but Anydesk is secure, much smaller footprint, and if you can have a direct connection doesn't seem to care too much about usage.  If you do need a license, it will be much lighter on the wallet.

AnyDesk works flawlessly without any installation required.  In fact, if using in a server environment as I described above, ***no*** installation is recommended.

Edit:  AmmyyAdmin is no longer recommended for several months now due to some security and technical concerns. Added AutoIT as a scripting capability to automate interaction with GUI/nearly any windows function.

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting without any comments.  My solution does bypass the Admin's server restrictions AND has potential for a script-based solution to move files back and forth to the server.

Comment: 2019 and the AnyDesk solution still works perfectly for a similar problem.