# Accessing SQL Reports server when url is only accessible by first using RDP

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdp

I have a client that needs me to set up a website that pulls sql reports from a separate server.  Currently the only way to access the url to the reports server is to first rdp into that server.  I tried creating a web services proxy class, but the url was unable to resolve due to the added protection.

Is there any way for me to pull the reports in my asp.net application from the other server without removing the rdp?  This is my first time trying this, so im not sure if i am going about this the correct way or if it is even possible to access that server from the client web application with the rdp in place.

EDIT

All my application needs to do is display pre-made reports to specific clients/groups based on their login credentials.  These clients/groups will not be creating or altering reports(at least not at this point in time).

Comment: This is a very silly requirement IMHO. RDP is meant for remote desktop sessions, not for tunneling URL/report requests. You should talk to the client and discuss other options (opening a secured port to the SSRS web service, for example).

Comment: You make a great point, and indeed it was a very silly request, but i figured id ask jic.  I changed the web server over to the server we were initially RDP'ing into, so no more of this funny business :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find its most likely not possible or probably very hard to do.

Perhaps you could obtain a copy of the database through replication or maybe a nightly bulk update and run the report against that, perhaps you could script a machine to remote desktop in and share the drives on it and get it to backup the db or similar.

In any case if you can't get a copy of the database I don't think you could feasibly generate any kind of report that allows user input to generate it.

EDIT:

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494086/351614) answer will get you started in connecting and triggering a file copy

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i edited my question bcz i forgot to say what my application needs to do.  I have never done this before as well, so if you can provide any extra details/links that will help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does seems like the only available option, i will give it a shot or just remove the rdp step to avoid all that.  Thanks