# Re-establishing a git svn clone on a separate machine

Tags: git, git-svn

I've got a git repository cloned from an external SVN repository through `git svn clone`. On a separate machine, I'd like to get this clone set up again, so I can update the git repository with recent SVN changes. How do I do this?

It seems using `git svn clone` or `git svn init` creates an empty repository, and `git svn fetch` uses a predefined URL. I don't want to have to reset my Git repository - I just want to pull the existing remote, re-link it to the same SVN, and continue with the `git svn rebase` to update Git with recent SVN changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-establish a `git svn` clone just by running the same commands you used to initialise the remote Git in the first place (but you might need to ensure you use the same `--prefix` in the `git svn clone`). It looks like Git keeps track of SVN metadata in the Git commit messages (`git-svn-id:`) to prevent duplicates.

[That is](http://jevon.org/wiki/Synchronising_SVN_and_Git):

1. `git svn clone -s https://openclerk.googlecode.com/svn/ openclerk -A svn-authors.txt --prefix ""` (the empty prefix is because the original Git repository used an empty prefix too)
2. `git remote add origin https://github.com/soundasleep/openclerk.git`
3. `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master`
4. `git pull`
5. Carry on with `git push`, `git svn rebase`, `git svn dcommit` as necessary

Answer (score 1):

If my svn repo did not follow standard layout this is what worked for me was:

```bash
git clone <git-repo>
cd <git-repo>
git svn init <svn-repo>
git config svn.authorsfile <your-authors-file>.txt
git svn fetch
(Optional) git branch -a  (should see a remotes/git-svn branch)
git checkout -b <some-branch-name> git-svn 
git checkout master
git rebase <some-branch-name>
#Now you can use "git svn rebase" etc.
git rebase origin/master
# Now you can push and pull
```

If my svn repo did follow the standard layout jevon's answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not copy your local repo files to the second machine.

`$ scp /path/to/first/repo user@second_machine_host:/path/to/second/repo`

or

`$ rsync -avz /path/to/first/repo user@second_machine_host:/path/to/second/repo`

or if you use `Windows`, you can just copy repo directory to the second machine by *Remote Desktop*, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9305105/792416).

Comment: That's the obvious option, but I don't have access from the first machine. I want to re-establish the previously cloned repository from scratch.