# How to copy folders from remote computer without using powershell or commandprompt

Tags: remote-access

Is it possible copy folders from remote computer without using powershell or cmd. Is there any other interface?

Comment: You can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304953/copy-files-from-remote-rdp-to-local-machine), and have your problem solved.

Comment: I wanted a programatical way.

Comment: What is stopping you from using PowerShell or command prompt?

Comment: Since I have to do copy many times, it takes considerably long time when executing powershell commands through c#. So I wanted a way that it takes less time than in powershell.